# React one time API call for multiple routes design

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, higher-order-components

- I am new to React and trying to implement an application. Basically
  my application have several routes. Each
  route is backed by the same set of back end data +some api calls
  specific to route taking back end data attributes as api params.
- So I wrote a Higher order component to call the
  API to retrieve the back end data,store the state in redux store and
  pass it as props to the wrapped component which works fine.

  ```
  const withData = (WrappedComponent) => {
      class DataWrapper extends Component {
          constructor() {
              this.state = {
                  c: {},
                  d: []
              };
          }

      componentDidMount(){
          this.props.fetchData();
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
          this.setState({
              c: nextProps.data.CSubset,
              d: nextProps.data.DSubset
          });
      }

      render() {
          return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state}/>;
      }
      const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
          data:state.appData
      });

      return connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchData})(DataWrapper);
  }

  export default withData;


  class AppComponent extends Component{
      componentDidMount(){
          this.props.fetchComponentSpecificData(c.dataAttribute);
      }
      render(){
          return <div />;
      }
  }

  export default connect(null,{fetchComponentSpecificData}(withData(AppComponent);
  ```
- But the issue is API gets called for all routes.It should be one
  time per full application flow.
- The component specific data fetch happens before the common back end data is available causing the component specific API call to fail.
- User can type in the URL and launch
  into any route within application and the API has to be called only
  once and the HOC has to systematically route to the correct route
  based on data.
  Please advise on the design approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the most "Reacty" way of doing this would be to implement the global API calls in the `componentWillMount` method of the top-level component (say, `AppComponent`). Right now, you have put it in a component that will be mounted for each subcomponent of your app, and it might be tricky to prevent the API call from being fired every time it mounts.

Using a HOC to provide those data to other components of your app is not a bad idea, but it makes your app a bit more implicit, and I don't think you're gaining a lot : you're adding a component with implicit behaviour instead of just adding a line in mapStateToProps.

Firing page-specific API calls *after* the global API call has succeeded is quite tricky. You're going to need a way to monitor the fact that the global API call has resolved, and in React/Redux way of thinking, this means dispatching an action. To dispatch actions asynchronously, you're going to need a Redux middleware such as [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) (I believe redux-thunk is a lot easier for beginners). Now, if you have a way to know whether or not the global API call is a success, you can wait for a specific action to be dispatched (say, `GLOBAL_API_CALL_SUCCESS`). Now, this is the part where I'm doing myself a bit of publicity : I've written [redux-waitfor-middleware](https://github.com/Polyconseil/redux-waitfor-middleware) that allows you to wait for a specific action to be dispatched. If you used it, it might look like this :

```
export async function fetchComponentSpecificData() {
  await waitForMiddleware.waitFor([GLOBAL_API_CALL_SUCCESS]);

  // perform actual API call for this specific component here
}
```

I'm not saying that waitFor middleware is the best tool to achieve this, but it's probably the easiest to understand if you're beginning!